# How to interpret the lambda function as shown?

Tags: c++, lambda, autosar

The following lines are taken from Autosar Adaptive Davinci source code and I have renamed/obscured parts of some information but kept the format intact.

```
class interface {
public:
    adaptive::core::Result<void> FunctionABC() {
        adaptive::core::Result<void> result{};
        // Do something
        return result;
    }
};
void main() {
    interfaceABC= std::make_unique<interface>();
    interfaceABC->FunctionABC().InspectError([this](adaptive::core::ErrorCode const& error) {
        logAMessage() << "Starting interface failed:" << error.Message() << ".";
    });
}
```

Here I am confused with the line about InspectError(). It feels like it is a lambda function  starting from [this] but I fully don't understand on when is InspectError called. Is it after FunctionABC() has returned a result or something else? Notice that it is error message with statement starting interface failed.

P.S. I do not see any definition of InspectError inside FunctionABC.

Thanks.

Comment: `InspectError` is a member of the object that `FunctionABC` returns. It is impossible to guess what that object does with the argument - read the documentation of `adaptive::core::Result.`

Comment: `InspectError()` is called on the returned object of `FunctionABC()` which is a `adaptive::core::Result<void>` object which has the `InspectError()` function.

Comment: AFAIK, capturing `this` only works in member functions and shouldn't compile in `main`.

Comment: you obsured too much. In `main` there is no `this`.

Comment: "...but I fully don't understand on when is InspectError called" you call it, right there in `main`. Do you mean.. "I dont understand when the lambda passed to `InspectError` is called?" ?

Comment: `InspectError` is called in main on the `adaptive::core::Result<void>` returned from `FunctionABC`. You wont find the definition of `InspectError` inside `FunctionABC` but in the definition of  `adaptive::core::Result<void>`

Comment: The lambdas are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Motti Yes there is another layer of class between main and FunctionABC which I obscured. And you're right the "this" refers to that obscured class object. But your comment only helped me more. Thanks.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah you better rephrased my question. But based on other comments I have a better understanding now. I think once FunctionABC has done his job and result is returned, it calls InspectError which decides if/when to call lambda. Am I right?

Comment: you should not obscure the code you post here. You should simplify and clarify it by removing anything not related to the question. Introducing additional errors is not simplifying nor clarifiying. Unfortunately, if you do not understand the code you cannot know what can be left out, and if the code is confidential you cannot show us the real code. At this point I think the best is to ask someone to whom you can show the actual code.

Comment: The [tag:davinci] tag is not for DaVinci Developer by Vector. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not actually sure what you are asking. `InspectError` is called in `main`. It is a member function of the `adaptive::core::Result<void>` returned from the call to `FunctionABC()`.

You cannot capture `this` in `main` because there is no `this` in `main`. Also `interfaceABC= std::make_unique<interface>();` makes no sense. Moreover `main` must return `int`.

Perhaps things get more clear for you when turning the code into something that actually compiles:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct adaptive_core_errorcode_mock {
    std::string Message() const { return "hello world";}
};


struct adaptive_core_result_mock { 
    using ftype = std::function<void(const adaptive_core_errorcode_mock&)>;
    ftype f;
    void InspectError(ftype g) { f = g;}

};


class interface {
public:
    adaptive_core_result_mock FunctionABC() {
        return {};
    }
};
int main() {
    auto x = std::make_unique<interface>();
    x->FunctionABC().InspectError([](adaptive_core_errorcode_mock const& error) {
        std::cout  << "Starting interface failed:" << error.Message() << ".";
    });
}
```

`FunctionABC` returns a `adaptive_core_result_mock` which has a method called `InspectError`. That method takes a callable of certain signature. Starting from here one has to guess. I guess the callable is stored to be called later. In the code above the lambda is never actually called. The `adaptive_core_result_mock` could call it via `f()`.